# Nuget Package Management issue - Unable to update the package in specific project

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

While compiling the Visual Studio solution I'm getting the below error. My specific project is looking for higher version(3.14.2), but the package it referenced is lower version. If i try to update from nuget package manager I'm getting an error, because another project looking for a lower version of this dll.

```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error NU1605  Detected package downgrade:
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory from 3.14.2 to
> 2.21.301221612. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.   TestProj -> TestProj2 0.1.219 ->
> Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication 1.1.0-preview ->
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.14.2)   TestProj
> -> TestProj2 0.1.219 -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>=
> 2.21.301221612)   Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel   D:\Services\TestProj.csproj 1
```

In my repo, shared.props file contains like this

```
<PKG_ACTIVEDIR>$(CxCachePath)\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.2.29.0</PKG_ACTIVEDIR>
```

Packages.Props file contains

```
<PackageReference Update="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="3.19.8" />
```

Also I have 2 folders under Packages like

```
> microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.2.29.0
```

Now where should I set VersionOverride to override this version on specific project and what is the syntax for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a situation where all the requirements of your project cannot be satisfied.

It's usually a bad practice to ignore the NU1605 warnings (it's a warning elevated to an error), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605.
Ignoring this warning can frequently lead to runtime errors. You essentially have components in your project that compiled against a higher version of the mentioned package. 
If you shove a lower version, you can end up with a runtime issue.

You have 2 options:

- Solve the problem, actually use a higher version that your transitive reference requires (3.14.2). Update all your references of this package (transitive and direct to 3.14.2
- Ignore the problem by suppressing the warning.

I don't think you need a version override here, the problem is not with the specified reference but with the transitive one.